# how to use flutter deep linking with custom url (own domain) if using firebase as a hosting

Tags: flutter, firebase-hosting, flutter-deep-link

How can i use my own domain for flutter deep linking if using firebase as a hosting provider.
The link works perfect when used with firebase hosting url but when used with personal domain it doesn't works and the web 404.html error page opens up.

```
   <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
//this works with firebase url 
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="firebaseurl.web.app" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />

//but this does not work
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="mydomain.com" />
   </intent-filter>
```

```
//but this does not work
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="mydomain.com" />
```

When i use this for my deep link it doesn't open the app instead redirect to the 404.html page.